# How to create DropDownMenu (RelativeLayout) with protruding part?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to animate a RelativeLayout. I want it to slide in from the bottom of the screen.

But in my implementation the most of RelativeLayout's content is lost.

A little more detail in the picture:

[image]

Please help!

Code:

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/sMenu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#e3e3e3"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    sMenu = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(id.sMenu);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    p2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, id.smth);
    p2.setMargins(0, 200, 0, 0);
    sMenu.setLayoutParams(p2);
 }


public void onClickStartAnimationButton(View view) {
    if (isBottom) {
        SlideToAbove();
        isBottom = false;
    } else {
        SlideToDown();
        isBottom = true;
    }
}
```

SlideToAbove:

```
public void SlideToAbove() {
Animation slide = null;
slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
        0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -4.5f);

slide.setDuration(400);
slide.setFillAfter(true);
slide.setFillEnabled(true);
sMenu.startAnimation(slide);

slide.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        sMenu.clearAnimation();

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                sMenu.getWidth(), displayHeight - 122);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, id.topPanel);
        sMenu.setLayoutParams(lp);

    }
});
```

SlideToDown:

```
public void SlideToDown() {
    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 5.2f);

    slide.setDuration(400);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    sMenu.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            sMenu.clearAnimation();
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            p2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, id.smth);
            p2.setMargins(0, 200, 0, 0);
            sMenu.setLayoutParams(p2);
            sMenu.requestLayout();
        }
    });
}
```

It seems to me that problem in setMargins() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooohh, it was so simple!

```
public void SlideToAbove() {
    ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(id.sMenu)).setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);

    ObjectAnimator mover = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(sMenu, "translationY", deltaY, 0);
    mover.setDuration(animationDuration);
    mover.start();
}

public void SlideToDown() {
    ObjectAnimator mover = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(sMenu, "translationY", 0, deltaY);
    mover.setDuration(animationDuration);
    mover.start();
}
```